# How can I get json information about a page that is on wordpress?

Tags: json, wordpress

I am communicating with the guys over at google and they are helping us with our site 'central.bet.co.za'.
The guys over at google are saying that they need me to supply them with "CORS Compliant Predictive JSON Endpoint for the same."

I really dont know where to find this information as I have never used json before or wordpress for that matter

I have tried installing the json.api.user plugin but that doesnt seem to be solving any problems either

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Wordpress core Rest API?
http://central.bet.co.za/wp-json/wp/v2/pages